# Do I need to update Xcode 9.0 and IOS 11 for my existing project, which is not approved by apple yet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios11

**I am building a project from last few days,the binary was build over 10.3.3 and Xcode version was 8.3.2.**

**I got this message from apple:**

> In-app purchases promoted on the App Store on iOS 11 require the new
>   StoreKit delegate method within the **SKPaymentTransactionObserver**
>   protocol, which handles App Store purchases. If you selected in-app
>   purchases to promote on the App Store during the iOS 11 beta period,
>   they will no longer show on the App Store until you implement this
>   method, rebuild your app with the GM version of Xcode 9, and submit
>   for review. For details, see Promoting Your In-App Purchases.

Currently my app submission status is **Developer Rejected** also there were some issues with **Business - Payment** metadata,

Currently **In App Purchase** is status is **In Review.**

So, should I need to update my **Xcode and IOS version** for next binary submission?

Thanks in advance for your help, *I am very new in IOS app development area!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to upgrade to Xcode 9, and changing development tools just as you're about to release is a bad idea. You'll want to move to the new tools when you can, but do it when you can update your source as needed and fully test the resulting binary. It's not something you should do when you're potentially one upload from release.

The message is about iOS 11 App Store In-App Purchase Promotions, which you can read about [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/). This is something you can choose to opt in to. It's not something that's required. To opt in to those promotions, you'd need to build using the iOS 11 SDK (which requires Xcode 9) and implement the delegate method mentioned.

Comment: My app is not approved yet, and need to upload new binary. So, can I submit my app using iOS 10.3.3 SDK, if I do not want to use the IAP Promotions feature?

Comment: Hi @MohammadFaisalIslam. If this answers all your questions, can you please click accept? I'm finally getting around to building my rep. ; ) Thanks.